# Break line in an include statement in Fortan

Tags: fortran, geany

I am new to Fortran and trying to run a code that is not my own. When I type the directory where a module is stored the directory is too long and I have to break the line. However when I try to do this an error comes up.

I am dealing with Fortran using Geany in Windows.

Code I am trying to run:

```
    include "G:\My Drive\06. Projects\02. CA_Spain\8. Replications\lmr_red_final\estimation_ed2_no_growth\src\model\params.f90"
    include "G:\My Drive\06. Projects\02. CA_Spain\8. Replications\lmr_red_final\estimation_ed2_no_growth\src\output.f90"
    include "G:\My Drive\06. Projects\02. CA_Spain\8. Replications\lmr_red_final\estimation_ed2_no_growth\src\glob.f90"
    include "G:\My Drive\06. Projects\02. CA_Spain\8. Replications\lmr_red_final & 
\estimation_ed2_no_growth\src\optimization\objective_function_mod.f90"
    include "G:\My Drive\06. Projects\02. CA_Spain\8. Replications\lmr_red_final\estimation_ed2_no_growth\src\optimization\optimization_mod.f90"
    include "G:\My Drive\06. Projects\02. CA_Spain\8. Replications\lmr_red_final\estimation_ed2_no_growth\src\optimization\data_statistics_mod.f90"

    program Msw
      use params
      use output
      use glob
      use objective_function_mod
      use optimization_mod
      use data_statistics_mod
    ...
```

And this is the error that comes up:

```
 - main_serial.f90:4:0: 
 - include "G:\My Drive\06. Projects\02. CA_Spain\8. Replications\lmr_red_final &
 - Error: Unclassifiable
 - statement at (1) main_serial.f90:5:1:
 - \estimation_ed2_no_growth\src\optimization\objective_function_mod.f90"
 - 1
 - Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
```

Comment: You introduced a space between the l and the &. But that should not cause a syntax error. What is your compiler? Which compiler command do you run? Or what do you click at before the error comes up?

Comment: General advise, never use full qualified paths in include statements, handle it through the `-I` (or equivalent) option of the compiler. Why use the include statement here in the first place, why not compile files (probably files with a module in it?) first and handle dependencies / linking through a Makefile.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I didn't know that one couldn't break line in this way. do you know how or have any example on how to change the cwd and refenrece the rest of folders from there using include? KR

Answer (score 2):

Include lines may not be continued, so you cannot break the character filename up in this way.

Instead you should find a way to shorten the file path reference, or (non-portably) allow the compiler to accept longer lines. Shortening the file path may involve renaming/moving the file, creating filesystem links, or using compiler search paths.

From Fortran 2018 (6.4 p4):

> An INCLUDE line shall appear on a single source line where a statement can appear

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that you can not break line in this way. is there a reference of the possible solutions that you point at the end, specially about 'creating filesystem links'.

Comment: Filesystem things will depend on your OS/filesystem, but you could create symbolic links (or equivalent).  However, I'd really suggest, as one of the comments also has, using compiler flags such as `-I` so that `include objective_function_mod.f90` works. And, indeed, considering using modules if possible instead of including things.